# Android - stopping NEW_OUTGOING_CALL events from looping?

Tags: android, listener

I have a `BroadcastReceiver` catching `ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL` events.

In the `onReceive()` method I'm sending the supplied number to a new `ListActivity`, where the user gets to choose various new destination numbers from a list.

When the user selects a new number from the list I'm then starting a new `ACTION_CALL` intent with the new number in the URI field. Alternatively, the result might be the original number.

Whatever the new number is, it has to be dialled immediately and not processed any further.

How can I let the `BroadcastReceiver` know that this resulting number shouldn't be processed yet again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I resolved this by implementing a "Bypass Prefix" in my `BroadcastReceiver`.  If my client app wants to call a number directly it simply prepends the prefix before invoking the `ACTION_CALL` Intent.

If the dialed number has the (hard coded) prefix, the `BroadcastReceiver` strips the prefix and allows the call to proceed as normal:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL.equals(action)) {
        String number = getResultData();
        if (number.startsWith(BYPASS_PREFIX)) {
             setResultData(number.substring(BYPASS_PREFIX.length()));
        } else {
             // do additional processing
        }
    }
}
```

This solves two problems in one go - not only does this stop the call looping, it also gives me a way to bypass the additional processing for specific numbers by storing the prefix in their phone book entries.

Comment: Hi Alnitak, I have come across a major issue with this on the HTC Hero, I use setResultData(null) to block the call however it doesn't seem to properly block the call. It blocks it ok but it buts a dialer icon in the used apps screen(hold down the home key) and when you click on this it appears to try to call again and disspears then, have yo come across anything like this? Works fine in vanilla Android but having major issues on the HTC Hero

Comment: I don't have a Hero.  It's possible that their special shell is also intercepting outbound call attempts, at a higher priority than your application.  Try changing your BroadcastReceiver's priority.

Comment: but through this i am unable to block out going calls on particular number

Answer (score 0):

The onReceive() method in Broadcast receiver receives an Intent as an argument.
Extract the Bundle from the Intent using Intent.getExtras().
This Bundle contains 3 key-value pairs as follows :

1. android.phone.extra.ALREADY_CALLED = null
2. android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER  = **98xxxxxx98**
3. android.phone.extra.ORIGINAL_URI   = tel:**98xxxxxx98**

**98xxxxxx98** is the number dialled by the user.

When the onReceive() is called again, this number changes to **98xxxxxx98*** or **0***
By checking for the asterisk(*) at the end of the dialled number, it can be inferred if the onReceive() method is called for the first time or the next subsequent times.